# Intershop 7.10. - fetching payment configuration

Tags: service, payment, intershop

We would like to fetch the payment configuration from Order in Java class (OrderBO extension). So far we have managed to fetch the service like this:

```
final OrderBOPaymentExtension<OrderBO> paymentExtension = getExtendedObject().getExtension(OrderBOPaymentExtension.EXTENSION_ID);

final PaymentBO paymentBO = paymentExtension.getPaymentBOs().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

PaymentServiceBO paymentServiceBO = paymentBO.getPaymentServiceBO();
```

Now we need to fetch the configuration, so we can read certain configuration parameters from the payment method. What is the best way to do that?

We know it is possible to fetch the payment configuration through the PO Factory like this:

```
PaymentConfigurationPOFactory f = (PaymentConfigurationPOFactory)NamingMgr.getInstance().lookupFactory(PaymentConfigurationPO.class);
PaymentConfigurationPO r = f.getConfigForIDAndDomain(iD, domain);
```

But we would like to avoid using deprecated code.

UPDATE:
What we are trying to achieve is access these BO parameters in Java code:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you write a `PaymentServiceBO` extension. Within that extension you can write getter methods to query for certain config values. The java code for accessing service configuration object is:

```
PaymentConfiguration paymentConfig = paymentServiceBO.getExtension(PersistentObjectBOExtension.class).getPersistentObject();
ServiceConfigurationBO serviceConfigurationBO = repository.getServiceConfigurationBOByID(paymentConfig.getManagedServiceConfiguration().getUUID());
ConfigurationProvider configProviderExtension = serviceConfigurationBO.getExtension(ConfigurationProvider.class);
Configuration configuration = configProviderExtension.getConfiguration();
Logger.debug(this, "payment service config keys = {}", configuration.getKeys());
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe PaymentConfiguration is deprecated. See PaymentConfigurationBO javadoc:

```
Deprecated since 7.6. Payment configurations are now represented via PaymentServiceBOs.
```

So you need to use PaymentServiceBO methods or write a business object extension that does what you want.

Comment: Ok, but what is the way to access payment configuration values through the paymentServiceBO? As you can see from my first code example, we are already working with PaymentServiceBO object, we are just trying to figure a way to access configuration values in Java code.

Comment: Methods like getPaymentCostBO have been moved to PaymentServiceBO from PaymentConfigurationBO. Is there a specific method you are looking for? Highly likely that the method u are looking for doesn't exist anymore because PaymentConfiguration is being deprecated.

Comment: I have updated the original question with a screenshot. It may be deprecated, but through Intershop BO it is possible to configure each service, including payment services through a tab called "Configuration". Our application is using service configuration params that are entered in that tab and we need to access those values in Java. Is there a way to access those?