# Recommended way to get payment methods/configurations in Intershop 7.10

Tags: intershop

Intershop 7.10, I am trying to understand what is a recommended way to retrieve payment methods/configurations for a domain.
I have examined ViewPaymentMethodList_52-ListAll pipeline in sld_ch_consumer_plugin cartridge and I see that it is using a deprecated pipelet GetPaymentConfigurationsByDomain, and when I examine that pipelet I see that it is using PaymentServiceMgr which is also deprecated.

[image: Deprecated pipelet]

What would be non-deprecated way to do that.

EDIT:
I am trying to access whether the payment method is enabled or disabled for a given application:
[image: payment method enabled flag]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate. Please, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365374/intershop-7-10-fetching-payment-configuration

Comment: @JohannesMetzner I am trying to access payment method congiguration, not payment service configuration, I have edited the question with screenshot of what I am trying to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but the information you're trying to get should become available when calling:

```
PaymentConfiguration config = paymentServiceBO.
    getExtension(PersistenObjectBOExtension.class).getPersistentObject();
// retrieve the list of activated application ids
config.createApplicationIDsIterator();
```